# laravel, Creating default object from empty value, when using Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-4, codeception

am using laravel, and codeception ..

i want to store the content of a form into a table called websites, i create a model Website.php, with the default template as documented, and a resource WebsiteController.php.

the routes are working as expected according to codeception.

i have the following code inside the store method of WebsiteController.php:

```
$website_name = Input::get('website_name');

$website = new Website;
$website->name = $website_name;       // line with the probleme
$website->save();

return 'success';
```

when i fill the form, and i send it, i get the error: Creating default object from empty value, pointing to the commented line above.

```
<?php

class Website extends Eloquent {
   // empty class
}
```

the output of dd($website);

```
object(Website)#158 (20) { ["fillable":protected]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(4) "link" [1]=> string(4) "type" [2]=> string(4) "name" [3]=> string(11) "description" } ["connection":protected]=> NULL ["table":protected]=> NULL ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["attributes":protected]=> array(0) { } ["original":protected]=> array(0) { } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["morphClass":protected]=> NULL ["exists"]=> bool(false) }
```

Comment: This might sounds obvious and perhaps you've tried, but can you hardcode a value to $website_name and see if you get the same issue? I suspect you're not actually retrieving the "website_name".

Comment: Can you post the output of a `var_dump($website);` right after you instantiate it? It would also be helpful to post the Website.php content.

Comment: @Hassan it was actually a clever idea i didn't think about, but it does not work.

Comment: what is your migration?